# Change the order of a routes variable in the front end NodeJs/Express/Jade

Tags: node.js, express, routes, pug

Novice to NodeJS and Express but lets say I have this route for mywebsite.com/tournaments.

```
router.get('/tournaments', function (req, res) {
    TournamentController.getAllTournaments(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            //render error
        } else {
            res.render('tournaments', {
                data: {
                    title: 'mysite',
                    command: 'tournaments',
                    user: req.session.user,
                    tournaments: docs
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

data.tournaments is an array of tournaments in order of their date. Lets say in the front end I have a select/option form where the user can choose date/prize/players as the order to sort the tournaments by. How can I sort the data.tournaments without having to call another route or refresh the page? I'm using Jade on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort them directly in the Browser via Javascript, either do it yourself or use a plugin like [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

If you don't wanna do that but do it on the server, you'll need an ajax call for that and a route that handles the sorting (based on the parameters you pass), and afterwards change the DOM according to the response. This goes without refreshing the page, but you'll need a route for that, or change the existing route and extend your controller to take optional parameters, something like

```
router.get('/tournaments/:sort?', function (req, res) {
    TournamentController.getAllTournaments(req.param('sort'), function (err, docs) {
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying the second approach using parameters in the get request. It looks like everything works, the server gets called and logs the sort variable, but the jade file doesn't update the order. Is there something else I'm supposed to do next?

Comment: Well you have to update the DOM yourself because the static page that you rendered from the jade file can't know that something changed. Either render the part of the page on the server, send it back and update it as it is, or make the partial available to client-side javascript and render it there.